# Load a external typescript library definition

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using monaco editor on my project, and I have to load some typescript .d.ts models into the monaco intellisense programmatically.

I'm using "Add Extra lib" for this purpose:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib("", libUrl);
```

My problem is that, nothing happens.
LibURL is a valid http url:
http:///127.0.0.1:1880/myapp/models/load/index.d.ts

That returns the definition file, how i can load it into monaco intellisense?
But I can't see the models on the intellisense

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have found what is wrong.

Monaco can't load full ts files like this:

```
declare class MyClass {
       
}
export default MyClass;
```

The model file, can only have functions and classes, no imports or exports or another kind of sentences are allowed:

```
declare class MyClass {
       
}
```

Comment: how do I import libraries then which have export statements in there?

Answer (score 1):

What you think is a URL is in fact the content of a typings file. You have to download the file yourself and feed it as parameter to `addExtraLib`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it this too, same error.

editor.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not find source file: 'ts:filename/xlsx-lib\dist\types\object.d.ts'.

monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib('file-content', 'ts:filename/xlsx-lib\dist\types\object.d.ts');

Comment: The [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.typescript.languageservicedefaults.html#addextralib) doesn't tell what the file path has to look like and what it's used for. However, I believe this is only to have a source "file" when showing type info etc. Try not specifying a path and see if that works. And I think that "ts:filename" prefix is wrong.